# WPF MenuItem with Image and IsCheckable set

Tags: wpf, menuitem

I've noticed that if you set IsCheckable and have an image for a MenuItem, when the item is checked, the image goes away.  Is is possible to get it to work similarly to the old .Net 2.0 so that when it's checked, the image has a border around it?
Thanks
Paul.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would need to restyle the MenuItems to achieve that. You can take the default Styles from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358533(v=VS.90).aspx), for say Aero, and pull out the Style (and relevant brushes) for the MenuItem. Once you have that, you can customize it all you want.

For MenuItem, you can actually just redefine the SubmenuItemTemplateKey and SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey ControlTemplate, by adding this to your application resources (pulled from file above and tweaked):

```
<Application x:Class="MyApplication.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>

    <Geometry x:Key="RightArrow">M 0,0 L 4,3.5 L 0,7 Z</Geometry>
    <Geometry x:Key="Checkmark">M 0,5.1 L 1.7,5.2 L 3.4,7.1 L 8,0.4 L 9.2,0 L 3.3,10.8 Z</Geometry>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuItemSelectionFill"
                         StartPoint="0,0"
                         EndPoint="0,1">
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStop Color="#34C5EBFF"
                          Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#3481D8FF"
                          Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}, ResourceId=SubmenuItemTemplateKey}"
                     TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Rectangle Name="Bg"
                       Fill="{TemplateBinding MenuItem.Background}"
                       Stroke="{TemplateBinding MenuItem.BorderBrush}"
                       StrokeThickness="1"
                       RadiusX="2"
                       RadiusY="2" />
            <Rectangle x:Name="InnerBorder"
                       Margin="1"
                       RadiusX="2"
                       RadiusY="2" />
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="24"
                                      Width="Auto"
                                      SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="37" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                                      SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="17" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        CornerRadius="3"
                        Margin="1"
                        Width="22"
                        Height="22">
                    <Grid>
                        <Path Name="Glyph"
                              Width="9"
                              Height="11"
                              Fill="#0C12A1"
                              FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
                              Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}"
                              Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon"
                                          Margin="1"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          ContentSource="Icon"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2"
                                  ContentSource="Header"
                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding MenuItem.Padding}"
                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="4"
                           Text="{TemplateBinding MenuItem.InputGestureText}"
                           Margin="{TemplateBinding MenuItem.Padding}" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Icon"
                     Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter TargetName="Icon"
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Collapsed" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                     Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="GlyphPanel"
                        Property="Background"
                        Value="#E6EFF4" />
                <Setter TargetName="GlyphPanel"
                        Property="BorderBrush"
                        Value="#CDD3E6" />
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="Icon"
                               Value="{x:Null}" />
                    <Condition Property="IsChecked"
                               Value="true" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter TargetName="Glyph"
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Visible" />
                <Setter TargetName="Icon"
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Collapsed" />
            </MultiTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted"
                     Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Bg"
                        Property="Fill"
                        Value="{StaticResource MenuItemSelectionFill}" />
                <Setter TargetName="Bg"
                        Property="Stroke"
                        Value="#8071CBF1" />
                <Setter TargetName="InnerBorder"
                        Property="Stroke"
                        Value="#40FFFFFF" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                     Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="#FF9A9A9A" />
                <Setter TargetName="GlyphPanel"
                        Property="Background"
                        Value="#EEE9E9" />
                <Setter TargetName="GlyphPanel"
                        Property="BorderBrush"
                        Value="#DBD6D6" />
                <Setter TargetName="Glyph"
                        Property="Fill"
                        Value="#848589" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}, ResourceId=SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey}"
                     TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Rectangle Name="Bg"
                       Fill="{TemplateBinding MenuItem.Background}"
                       Stroke="{TemplateBinding MenuItem.BorderBrush}"
                       StrokeThickness="1"
                       RadiusX="2"
                       RadiusY="2" />
            <Rectangle x:Name="InnerBorder"
                       Margin="1"
                       Stroke="Transparent"
                       StrokeThickness="1"
                       RadiusX="2"
                       RadiusY="2" />
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="24"
                                      Width="Auto"
                                      SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="37" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                                      SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="17" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        CornerRadius="3"
                        Margin="1"
                        Width="22"
                        Height="22">
                    <Grid>
                        <Path Name="Glyph"
                              Width="9"
                              Height="11"
                              Fill="#0C12A1"
                              FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
                              Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}"
                              Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon"
                                          Margin="1"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          ContentSource="Icon"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2"
                                  ContentSource="Header"
                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding MenuItem.Padding}"
                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="4"
                           Text="{TemplateBinding MenuItem.InputGestureText}"
                           Margin="{TemplateBinding MenuItem.Padding}"
                           Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <Path Grid.Column="5"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      Margin="4,0,0,0"
                      Fill="{TemplateBinding MenuItem.Foreground}"
                      Data="{StaticResource RightArrow}" />
            </Grid>
            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"
                   AllowsTransparency="true"
                   Placement="Right"
                   VerticalOffset="-3"
                   HorizontalOffset="-2"
                   IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsSubmenuOpen,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                   Focusable="false"
                   PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}">
                <theme:SystemDropShadowChrome Name="Shdw"
                                              Color="Transparent">
                    <ContentControl Name="SubMenuBorder"
                                    Template="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}, ResourceId=SubmenuContent}}"
                                    IsTabStop="false">
                        <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="true"
                                      Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}, ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer}}">
                            <ItemsPresenter Margin="2"
                                            KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"
                                            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"
                                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                            Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </ContentControl>
                </theme:SystemDropShadowChrome>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation"
                     Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="PART_Popup"
                        Property="PopupAnimation"
                        Value="None" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted"
                     Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="InnerBorder"
                        Property="Stroke"
                        Value="#D1DBF4FF" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Icon"
                     Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter TargetName="Icon"
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Collapsed" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                     Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="GlyphPanel"
                        Property="Background"
                        Value="#E6EFF4" />
                <Setter TargetName="GlyphPanel"
                        Property="BorderBrush"
                        Value="#CDD3E6" />
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="Icon"
                               Value="{x:Null}" />
                    <Condition Property="IsChecked"
                               Value="true" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter TargetName="Glyph"
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Visible" />
                <Setter TargetName="Icon"
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Collapsed" />
            </MultiTrigger>
            <Trigger SourceName="PART_Popup"
                     Property="Popup.HasDropShadow"
                     Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Shdw"
                        Property="Margin"
                        Value="0,0,5,5" />
                <Setter TargetName="Shdw"
                        Property="Color"
                        Value="#71000000" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted"
                     Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Bg"
                        Property="Fill"
                        Value="{StaticResource MenuItemSelectionFill}" />
                <Setter TargetName="Bg"
                        Property="Stroke"
                        Value="#8571CBF1" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                     Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="#FF9A9A9A" />
                <Setter TargetName="GlyphPanel"
                        Property="Background"
                        Value="#EEE9E9" />
                <Setter TargetName="GlyphPanel"
                        Property="BorderBrush"
                        Value="#DBD6D6" />
                <Setter TargetName="Glyph"
                        Property="Fill"
                        Value="#848589" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

You would need to add a reference to PresentationSource.Aero to your project and you may want to darken up the colors for the GlyphPanel when checked.

Comment: I love to see how simple things in Windows Forms go backwards in WPF ... :(

Comment: Yep. Like so many other poor abstractions, one is left with writing in XML--a markup language--what should be code.

Comment: Not only is this `ControlTemplate` incredibly verbose, but it is also listed ***TWICE***, so it appears even more verbose than it really is.

Comment: @MikeNakis - The `ResourceId` are different between the two control templates and they are different. Yeah, they are verbose, but unfortunately, that's needed for some of the WPF styles.