# Getting the width of the icon area of a context menu

Tags: winapi, popup

I need to get the width of the icon area of a context menu using the Windows API (>= Windows XP if this matters). What I mean by icon area you can see in [this question, there is an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276826/system-windows-controls-menuitem-without-icon-area). It is a space reserved for icons on the left side of the menu.

I scanned through the wealth of information you can get via [SystemParametersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetSystemMetrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but found nothing. But there has to be some default value, right? How could I get it?

Answer (score 2):

A native win32 menu does not really support icons so you can't really call it the icon area. In a basic menu the size of that area is SM_CXMENUCHECK wide (Plus SM_CXEDGE for padding probably) For Vista+ you might be able to find some [better metrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756947.aspx) with the MENU_POPUP* constants and GetThemeInt. AFAIK the exact layout and border constants required to replicate classic Win95+ menus are not documented.

Since you are talking about icons I assume you want to add icons to your menu so your width should probably be max(yourIconWidth,GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXMENUCHECK)) + padding. [This old MSJ article](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0198/coolmenu.aspx?Give%20Your%20Applications%20the%20Hot%20New%20Interface%20Look%20with%20Cool%20Menu%20Buttons) is probably the best menu owner draw tutorial out there, and codeproject has its own [menu article section](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/#Custom%20menus) with several different owner draw implementations. (MS Office and Visual Studio use custom stuff as well)

As a final note, since you said XP+ you should be able to use HBMMENU_CALLBACK and only worry about the icon and not the rest of the menu drawing...

Comment: If you want those fancy icon menus your best bet is probably two implementations; HBMMENU_CALLBACK or full owner draw on NT5 and using the new 32bit (pre multiplied alpha) menu bitmap support on NT6+

Comment: Anders, thanks for the tips. I just need to measure the width to do some positioning in a special case. So no drawing involved. The theming stuff is interesting, I experimented a bit. Seems like my best bet (on Vista+) would be something like MENU_POPUPBORDERS+MENU_POPUPCHECK+MENU_POPUPGUTTER+MENU_POPUPSEPARATOR for the width. But the border seems to change depending on the image size. The more I think about it the more appealing seems to just estimate the size.