# Remove spaces between and after menu list in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this menu items in my WPF application. I noticed big spaces between and after the menu list.

This is how it looks like in the designer:

[image]

which seemed to be just fine except, there are too much space on both sides.

Then, when I run the application, it looks like this:

[image]

Now, there are spaces all around the menu item.

Here's my XAML code:

```
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_File" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontSize="12">
                <MenuItem Header="Exit" Width="Auto" Height="20">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ExitToApp"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </DockPanel>
```

How can I remove spaces around the menu item?

Comment: You explicitly set the`Height="20"`, it can be a reason. Also try to use `MenuItem` without Icon or restrict its height and see what happens

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem without icon area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276826/system-windows-controls-menuitem-without-icon-area)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski already tried doing that. The spaces went bigger.

Comment: @Rekshino I'm totally fine with the icon area since I'm going to add icons later on. I'm more concerned about the top and bottom areas.