# How to remove the first and third columns of WPF's MenuItem control

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, menuitem

I would like to remove the first column (used for icon) and third column (used for shortcut key) of a `WPF Menu control` (as shown in image 1 below). I have tried using following hack, and it does hide the first and third columns (as shown in image 2 below). But I want to properly remove these two columns using some sort of editing template or so.

**My hacked XAML to hide first and third columns**:

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <MenuItem Header="_File">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                 <StackPanel Margin="-31,0,-18,0"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <MenuItem Header="_New" />
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

**Display of the image1 (without hack) and image 2 with hack**:

[image]

I have tried to edit the `menuitem` template in [VS2019 Blend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/creating-a-ui-by-using-blend-for-visual-studio?view=vs-2019). But in the property window on the right (shown in image 3 below) of Blend, I am not sure as to what I need to do there to remove these columns. And when I right click on the `MenuItem` on the left in the Blend, and click on `Edit Template`, I get a XAML copy of MainWidndow.xaml file (
shown below) with `ControlTemplates` and `styles` etc. I am not sure what I need to modify in that xaml template to remove these two columns. Maybe someone with better knowledge can help.

**Screenshot of Design view of MainWindow.xaml inside VS2019 Blend**:

[image]

**MainWindow.xaml [After clicking in Edit Template]**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp_Test4RTB.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        ......>
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Background" Color="#FFF0F0F0"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Border" Color="#FF999999"/>
        .............
        <MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter x:Key="MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter"/>
        <Geometry x:Key="DownArrow">M 0,0 L 3.5,4 L 7,0 Z</Geometry>
        <Geometry x:Key="UpArrow">M 0,4 L 3.5,0 L 7,4 Z</Geometry>
        <Geometry x:Key="RightArrow">M 0,0 L 4,3.5 L 0,7 Z</Geometry>
        <Geometry x:Key="Checkmark">F1 M 10.0,1.2 L 4.7,9.1 L 4.5,9.1 L 0,5.2 L 1.3,3.5 L 4.3,6.1L 8.3,0 L 10.0,1.2 Z</Geometry>
        <Style x:Key="MenuScrollButton" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
            <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Hover"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="6" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                                <ScrollContentPresenter CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}" CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Grid.Column="0" Focusable="false" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource MenuScrollButton}">
                                <RepeatButton.Visibility>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter}" ConverterParameter="0" FallbackValue="Visibility.Collapsed">
                                        <Binding Path="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                        <Binding Path="VerticalOffset" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                        <Binding Path="ExtentHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                        <Binding Path="ViewportHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </RepeatButton.Visibility>
                                <Path Data="{StaticResource UpArrow}" Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}"/>
                            </RepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineDownCommand}" CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Grid.Column="0" Focusable="false" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource MenuScrollButton}">
                                <RepeatButton.Visibility>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter}" ConverterParameter="100" FallbackValue="Visibility.Collapsed">
                                        <Binding Path="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                        <Binding Path="VerticalOffset" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                        <Binding Path="ExtentHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                        <Binding Path="ViewportHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </RepeatButton.Visibility>
                                <Path Data="{StaticResource DownArrow}" Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}"/>
                            </RepeatButton>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Border x:Name="templateRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                    <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" Grid.Column="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Background}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Border}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Background}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Border}"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Border x:Name="templateRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                    <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" Grid.Column="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Bottom" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=templateRoot}">
                        <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" Background="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Background}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Border}" Padding="2">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                                <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Separator}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,2,0,2" Width="1"/>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Background}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Border}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Border x:Name="templateRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Height="22" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <Grid Margin="-1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="22" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                    <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" Background="{StaticResource MenuItem.Selected.Background}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource MenuItem.Selected.Border}" ClipToBounds="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="22" Margin="-1,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden" Width="22">
                        <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}" Height="11" Width="10"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="menuHeaderContainer" ContentSource="Header" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="menuGestureText" Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0.7" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Background}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Border}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Background}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Border}"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Border x:Name="templateRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Height="22" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <Grid Margin="-1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="22" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                    <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" Background="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Background}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Border}" Height="22" Margin="-1,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden" Width="22">
                        <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="{DynamicResource Checkmark}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}" Height="11" Width="9"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0.7" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Path x:Name="RightArrow" Grid.Column="5" Data="{StaticResource RightArrow}" Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false" HorizontalOffset="-2" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" VerticalOffset="-3">
                        <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" Background="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Background}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Border}" Padding="2">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                                <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,2,0,2" Width="1"/>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Border}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="RightArrow" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,0"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Background}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Border}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,0"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="New" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute"  Executed="CommandBinding_Executed" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Style="{DynamicResource MenuItemStyle1}" Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Command="New" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem without icon area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276826/system-windows-controls-menuitem-without-icon-area)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MenuItem` has different templates depending on the value of its `Role` property. Here is an example that you should be able to modify according to your requirements:

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <MenuItem Header="_File">
        <MenuItem Header="_New">
            <MenuItem.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="&#347;" Color="#FFF0F0F0" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="&#348;" Color="#FF999999" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="&#349;" Color="#FF212121" />

                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="&#350;" Color="#FFD7D7D7" />

                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="&#351;" Color="#3DDADADA" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="&#352;" Color="#FFDADADA" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="&#353;" Color="#FF707070" />

                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="&#354;" Color="#3D26A0DA" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="&#355;" Color="#FF26A0DA" />

                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="&#356;" Color="#3D26A0DA" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="&#357;" Color="#FF26A0DA" />

                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="&#358;" Color="#0A000000" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="&#359;" Color="#21000000" />

                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Border x:Name="templateRoot"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="menuHeaderContainer"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        ContentSource="Header"
                                        RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                        Margin="{TemplateBinding MenuItem.Padding}"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource &#356;}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource &#357;}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource &#353;}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource &#358;}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource &#359;}" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </MenuItem.Template>
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

You'll find the default templates on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/main/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/Themes/PresentationFramework.Aero2/Themes/Aero2.NormalColor.xaml).

Comment: @nam: Did you really downvote this? What kind of answer are you looking for then?

Comment: I did not downvote it. Actually I only upvote. If I don't understand a response I blame it to myself (thinking maybe I am lacking required knowledge to understand that response). Someone else downvoted your response and my post at the same time, as well.

Comment: So what's left to your question?

Comment: For some reasons, I am still struggling to implement your response. Based on your response, I tried modifying the edited template from my above post but was not sure if I am on the right track.

Comment: I just tested by replacing my menu control with the one from your response, and it worked. Now, I am trying to implement it through a resource.

Comment: Since I have multiple menuitems, I implemented your suggested code using a `Resource` as follows, and it worked perfectly for my needs (thank you, myupvote +1): a) I moved your `ControlTemplate` to `Window.Resouces` giving it a key. b) and used it as follows `<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">   <MenuItem Header="_File">   <MenuItem Header="_New" Template="{StaticResource myControlTemplate}"/>                 <MenuItem Header="_Open" Template="{StaticResource myControlTemplate}" /> ...other menuitems etc.`

Comment: Is there a way to add a button or a link to a Mahapps metro's ShowInputAsync() dialog? I've posted the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68537386/1232087)